# Slicing after an index

Tags: r, subset

I have a data table in R and want to take all rows after a certain index.  For a minimal example, I tried

```
x <- c(1,2,3)
x[2:]
```

which is the correct syntax in Python but gives an error in R.  I know I could do

```
x[2:length(x)]
```

but that somehow strikes me as verbose.  Is that the best way to do it?

Comment: Yes, or you can do `x[-1]` to remove the first column, or `2:ncol(x)` if `length` is confusing.  Also, for rows you need a comma `x[-1,]`

Comment: Also, that `x` is a vector, not a `data.table`...

Comment: Also possible: `tail(x, -theindex)`. Verbose?